# crystal report is not displayin

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

this is my aspx page code

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" />

    </form>
</body>
```

and this is what i run at page load

```
    ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
    DBman db = new DBman(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString);
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string type=Request.QueryString["type"];
    string query = (string)Session["query"];
    string bg = (string)Session["bg"];
    string rh = (string)Session["rh"];
    string key = (string)Session["key"];
    if (type =="type")
    {
        DataTable dt = db.getTable(query);//this works custom class to run query
       rd.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Staff/BrowseDonors.rpt"));
       rd.SetDataSource(dt);
       rd.SetParameterValue("BloodGroup",bg);
       rd.SetParameterValue("Rh", rh);
       rd.SetParameterValue("keyword", key);
       CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
       CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();

    }
```

what is going wrong all values are passed correctly but the page is blank not even the reportviewer is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to create a new instance of Report Document within the page load.

```
protected ReportDocument rd;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string type=Request.QueryString["type"];
    string query = (string)Session["query"];
    string bg = (string)Session["bg"];
    string rh = (string)Session["rh"];
    string key = (string)Session["key"];
    if (type =="type")
    {
       rd = new ReportDocument();
       DataTable dt = db.getTable(query);//this works custom class to run query
       string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Staff/BrowseDonors.rpt");
       rd.Load(reportPath);
       rd.SetDataSource((DataTable)dt);
       rd.SetParameterValue("BloodGroup",bg);
       rd.SetParameterValue("Rh", rh);
       rd.SetParameterValue("keyword", key);
       CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

found out that the iiS Express dont support Crystal report think this is the case